# How to update all posts but the current one (post__not_in not working?)

Tags: get-posts, post-status, wp-update-post

I'm trying to unpublish (set post_status to draft) all posts when a new one (with specific conditions that don't really matter right now) is published.

Here's what I currently have:

```
function rsc_unpublish_all_ads( $post_id ) {

    // don't do anything if the post is not an ad
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    if ( 'rsc-ads' != $post_type ) return;

    // select all ads other than the current one
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__not_in' => array($post_id),
        'post_type' => 'rsc-ads',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    $published_ads = get_posts( $args );

    if ( !empty($published_ads) ) {

        // set each of the published ads as draft
        foreach ($published_ads as $published_ad) {

            // check again just for the sake of it?
            if ( $published_ad->ID == $post_id ) return;

            $unpublish = array(
                'ID' => $published_ad->ID,
                'post_status' => 'draft'
            );

            wp_update_post( $unpublish );
        }

    }

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'rsc_unpublish_all_ads' );
```

What happens is all rsc-ads posts are set to draft **including** the one I'm saving/updating – even though I'm checking against it twice (`post__not_in` in the `$args` AND comparing the ID in the foreach loop).

I know `$post_id` is correct because I'm checking for post type at the beginning of my function and that works fine.

Any ideas how to exclude the currently-being-saved post from being updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a more elegant way of updating your posts using the global `$wpdb`.

```
function rsc_unpublish_all_ads( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

// select all ads other than the current one
$args = array(
    'nopaging' => true,
    'post__not_in' => array($post_id),
    'post_type' => 'rsc-ads',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'fields'=>'ids'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

$published_ads = $query->posts;//array of post ids

 if ( !empty($published_ads) ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $ids = implode(',', $published_ads);

    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_status = 'draft' WHERE ID IN ($ids)");

 }

}
    add_action( 'save_post_rsc-ads', 'rsc_unpublish_all_ads', 10, 3 );
```

I think you were having a problem calling `wp_update_post()` while the function was still running. In this implementation, if the `$query` is returning the post IDs properly, you make one trip to the database and fix all the posts without running a loop. Note I changed your hook to be specific to the "rsc-ads" post type so it will only fire on this post type.

Comment: Thanks for this, using `$wpdb` worked great! Note: had to use `$published_ads = wp_list_pluck( $query->posts, 'ID' );` to get the array of posts IDs.

Comment: @Jusi glad it worked but I'm surprised you needed that function when the WP_Query I wrote returns only the post IDs as an array. You may want to consider using the `transition_post_status` hook going forward since the `save_post_rsc-ads` hook is going to fire when you're still in draft of the new ad. I believe you only want this function to fire when you go from some status into 'publish' for the first time but I could be wrong. If so, write back and I'll be happy to modify the function for you.

Comment: @Jusi You needed that `wp_list_pluck()` because you used `get_posts()` that returned an array of `$post` objects as `$published_ads`.

Answer (score 0):

You ended it by return, so your function will stopped when found the post that should not (or should?) be update, instead return it:

```
        if ( $published_ad->ID == $post_id ) return;
```

you can:

```
            if ( $published_ad->ID != $post_id ) {
// unpublishing ads
}
```

to get current post id in front end:

```
get_the_ID();
```

while in wp admin editor:

```
$_GET['post'];
```

dont forget adding condition is_admin  to make sure you executing this in wp admin

Comment: You're of course right about return, I changed that now. I shouldn't really need to use that if statement anyway, since `post__not_in` is set to ID of post being saved. It hasn't helped though, it's still selecting ALL posts, including the one being edited.

Comment: have you try   `if ( $published_ad->ID != $post_id ) { do unpublishing others  }`

or after loop of unpublished:


 `$republish = array(
                'ID' => $post_id,
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            );

            wp_update_post( $republish );`


yes that's inefficient, but just to prepared if your current ad post being unpublished